# Combining Left and Right Hook Speaker Wires Into One Speaker

Tags: speakers, watts

So I have an mp3 player, http://dx.com/p/94814, and the mp3 player comes with a left and right speaker output. For my equipment, I only have one speaker, not two. Can I just combine the left and right wires together and hook them up to the speaker? So left and right + together and left and right - together and just plug them into the speaker? If I do that, is there a possibility that I might blow up the speaker? For example, if both outputs output 10 watts each, does that mean 20 watts is going to the speaker and if the speaker only supports 10 watts it will blow?

Comment: While I appreciate you accepting my answer, it's a good idea to wait a while to see what collects before picking one. Once a answer is accepted, others are more likely to skip over the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help as well. Sorry, I was online doing some research and felt that your answer was dead on to what I've been reading about combining speakers, but you're right. I'll give it more time to see if there are other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shorting the wires is not a good idea.  Each signal is produced by a separate amplifier, which is probably using feedback to make sure it is the voltage it is supposed to be.  When you short the two together, the two ampliers will be fighting each other.

To be safe, put a 4 Ω resistor in series with each lead before shorting them together as you describe.  That is a total of 4 resistors, one in series with each of the + and - outputs for each side.  Then connect the single speaker between the two resistors coming from the + outputs on one side, and the other side of the speaker to the two resistors coming from the - outputs.  The speaker will then effectively emit the average of the two stereo signals, which is basically the mono signals.

There are other ways this could be done, but without any specific information about the circuit, this is the conservative approach.  It will waste a little power, but if you really care, get the right speakers.

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately this is for a toy car, so there is no way for me to add a second speaker to fit. So my setup really is just batteries, an mp3 player and a speaker. I do like the resistor idea, so I will look into it further.

Answer (score -2):

It is theoretically possible to blow the speaker that way, but in practice, you will use common sense and not turn the volume up so loud that the sound distorts. The power delivered to the speaker is not a constant; it is related to the volume.

Another concern is whether one channel's output could damage the other.  Again, possible, but I'm not aware of this being a problem in practice.